# Need most popular value in mysql comma separated value?

Tags: php, mysql

my tags table

```
| id  | tags         
| --- | ------------ 
| 1   | css,html,php 
| 2   | php,java,css      
| 3   | java,c++,ios
```

need out put like

```
| tags  | tags         
| ---   | ------------ 
| css   |  2  
| php   |  2    
| java  |  1
| html  |  1
| c++   |  1
| ios   |  1
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: normalize the database to avoid storing comma separated values and prevent complexity.

Comment: If I was going *there*, I wouldn't start from *here*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what DB extension you are using. You can try this -

```
// Fetch the data by executing- 
"SELEC GROUP_CONCAT(tags) tags FROM my_tags";

// Then explode them
$tags = $row['tags'];
$tags_array= explode(',', $tags);

//Count the values
$counts = array_count_values($tags_array);

// Sort
$counts = arsort($counts);
```

This is like an algorithm. Implement it with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.. Hope it will help.

```
SELECT       `value`,
             COUNT(`value`) AS `value_occurrence` 
    FROM     `my_table`
    GROUP BY `value`
    ORDER BY `value_occurrence` DESC
    LIMIT    1;
```

Comment: This wouldn't help as `tags` have different values. So `COUNT` would be `1` for all values.

Comment: To get a list of values and the number of their appearances: Give it try. 

select col_name, count(col_name) c from table
group by col_name
order by c desc;

Comment: Please check this out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Answer (score 1):

This may help:
`select group_concat(tags) from tags group by tag;`